# Unable to install rtools and configure the path correctly

Tags: r, devtools

I followed [this](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/R/ICPSR/R-install-instructions.html) instructions to install R and Rstudio, specifically, in the installation of R, I set `C:\R\R-3.4.1` as the folder to store R instead of `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1` to avoid any possible issues with space in the path. Then I followed [this](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp/install-rtools-for-rcpp/) instruction step by step to download and install the latest version of `rtools`. Specifically, during the installation of rtools, there is a message box
[image]
And I followed the instruction and click both of them.

Then I open `Rstudio` (at this moment, it is all fresh, I didn't install any R packages except for those basic ones that comes with Rstudio) and `install.packages("devtools")` then everything looks smooth

```
package ‘withr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\FTXX\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpK2EE70\downloaded_packages
```

Then

```
library(devtools)
find_rtools(T)
Error: running command '"C:/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-
environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' had status 65535
```

My system path is

```
Sys.getenv()['PATH']
PATH                     C:\R\R-
3.4.1\bin\x64;c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\mingw_32\bin;C:\R\R-
3.4.1\bin;C:\Program
                     Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\;C:\Users\FTXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3;C:\Users\FTXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\FTXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\bin
```

I also found that the output of `Sys.getenv()['PATH']` and `shell("PATH")` generates different message. In `Shell('PATH')` is says

```
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-
rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin /c PATH' had status 127 
2: In shell("PATH") : 'PATH' execution failed with error code 127
```

I also output some variables

```
Sys.which("ls.exe")
ls.exe 
"c:\\Rtools\\bin\\ls.exe" 
Sys.which("gcc.exe")
gcc.exe 
"c:\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

and my R is 3.4.1 and I am on Windows 10. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In my recent installations, I've always needed to open /etc/*/Makeconf and modify the BINPREF parameter, I think it was, currently `c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/`.

Comment: @Frank could you please elaborate on that? like where is this Makeconf  and BINPREF, my knowledge about operating system is so limited and I apologize for that

Comment: If you type `list.dirs(file.path(R.home(), "etc"))[ -1 ]` you'll see some folders. Inside each there should be a file named Makeconf that you can edit with notepad. There should be a line like `BINPREF ?= something` and you might need to update that line to point to Rtools' bin folder. At least, that's what I've found I have to do each time. There is probably some better way, but I'm not very OS savvy either (using Windows here).

Comment: @Frank I follow your instruction, it indeed returns two folders `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/i386" "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/x64"`, I don't know why there is 2 folders, as I also see my `.libpaths()` gives me 2 folders, I guess one is for system, the other is for user. Anyway, I think `"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/etc/x64"` is the right one. But is is not a valid path right? I put it into the bar on the top of the windows, it says windows can't find it, check spelling and try again...Should I change some special characters like `~`

Comment: Hm, yeah, I'm seeing the same. I can think of a couple ways to get there... you could manually guess which folders are in that path, starting from `c:/Program Files` and clicking through. Alternately, Start Menu > cmd will open a window where you can type `cd` and then the folder from R, after which `start .` will open the folder. (At least that works on Windows 10.) Btw, the two folders are for two different modes the computer can be run in, 32-bit and 64-bit. 64-bit is better, and the other way is available mostly for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Frank I did find that file and originally, that line is `BINPREF ?= c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/`. Now I changed it into `BINPREF ?= c:/Rtools/bin/`. But the weird thing is that it says I don't have permission to save in this location. Contact administrator to obtain permission. I've been tortured this desktop for a year and it never ask me for permission....

Comment: Hm, I hate when that happens.It might be that your problem is different than mine, so I don't know if it's worth it to contact your administrator over my suggestion. Maybe someone else will come by with a different idea or you could try asking somewhere else. Alternately, maybe this is just a devtools problem and you could ask there https://github.com/hadley/devtools

Comment: @ No problem. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: Had the same problem with Windows asking for permission. Other people may find the following guide helpful to be able to take ownership of the appropriate directories and switch off the read-only access: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-failed-to-enumerate-objects-in-the-container

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the **installr** package to download and install **Rtools**.

try this in your IDE
I did it in RStudio.

```
install.packages("installr")
```

Then, when the package is installed, make it available with

```
library("installr")
```

At this point, you are good to go!

Install Rtool using the following

```
install.Rtools()
```